# Necessarily false propositions

Tags: philosophy-of-language

Are these a thing, and does their existence imply anything interesting? It’s less clear to me necessarily true propositions exist, besides it’s necessarily true these be false.

Sentences/propositions like "I'm too tired to say/write the word tired" or “I’m too nervous to write/say the word sex”.

Isn’t that kind of weird? Do they have a global notion of truth/falsity contra Tarski?

Just wondering if necessarily false propositions are even a thing. Are they studied by any logicians or linguistics experts? If yes, why are the studied?

Comment: "It’s less clear to me necessarily true propositions exist, besides it’s necessarily true these be false." What about "This is a sentence."? Or, "I am writing these words."?

Comment: @NoahSchweber What exactly are “this” and “these” referring to? I do not personally immediately find those two examples “true”. It’s like what about “this are that”? The two examples in my question really jump out as false to me. Without the same ambiguity. But maybe these are my own idiosyncrasies. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What does "I" refer to in your examples? I don't see why reference to the speaker is any less ambiguous than reference to the sentence. How about "The sentence that you are currently reading is in English?"

Comment: @NoahSchweber but I guess I should ask first, are there such things as necessarily true or false propositions? Is that something everyone agrees on?

Comment: @NoahSchweber in regards to your sentence, if I am supposed to be able to translate it into other languages, it isn’t necessarily true. We can say sentences must be translatable and preserve their truth values. The two sentences I gave have that normal feature.

Comment: "We can say sentences must be translatable and preserve their truth values." We can, can we (and I suppose "cette phrase est en Français" doesn't count as the right truth-value-preserving translation into French of "this sentence is in English")? Since I can't guess where the goalposts will move next, I guess I'll stop.

Comment: Necessarily false propositions are relative to necessarily true propositions (r→(p→r)), so as proposition itself is meaningful and perhaps very interesting since we can confidently have some "revelation" out of the blue. But not arbitrary valid sentence is a proposition like the Liar sentence or your above paradoxical ones. Valid sentences can be eventually and definitely recognized by its grammar/production rules/TMs in so far as it belongs to Chomsky's type-0 recursively enumerable class, but they may be paradoxical very easily as reflected in your above cited common casual communications...

Comment: Re your "It’s less clear to me necessarily true propositions exist, besides it’s necessarily true...",in a sense you're rightful to have such intuition as the ancient Mahayana Buddhist [Shrangama Sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) hinted: *To speak of the false is to reveal the true. But both the false and the true are false themselves... Between them the two in fact have no nature. Thus they are likened to entwining reeds... If you don’t grasp, there is no non-illusion...*

Comment: Yes there are obviously some propositions that are necessarily false.  They used to be called self contradictory propositions in philosophy, but since people respect mathematics more people seem to roll with Mathematical phrases. Mathematics states any statement that is always false is a "contradiction". This differs from the philosophy context. They are not identical even though the same terminology is used. Secondly sentences ARE NOT propositions. People need to stop saying that. Propositions are not sentences & they are not statements either by definition.  All squares have 5 sides is false

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone I know I ask some weird stuff that is often just wrong @Logikal thanks that terminology helped me find some articles already. And thanks Double Knot. Given me more to research and think about.

Comment: “p, therefore p” is necessarily true. “p, therefore not-p” is necessarily false.

Answer (score 1):

> Necessarily false propositions

Strictly speaking, the only necessity we know of is logical necessity. Thus, we don't know of any necessarily true or necessarily false statements outside logical fallacies and logical truths.

We also don't know of any contingent sentence which is necessarily true or necessarily false unless as a result of assuming some premise, in which case the sentence is necessarily true or false only relatively to the assumption.

For example, if I assume that x = 2 together with the usual meanings for the symbols 'x', '=' and '2', then necessarily x = 2. But it would be absurd to assert that necessarily x = 2.

Logical truths and fallacies themselves are only necessary dependent on assuming the usual meaning of logical connectors such as the conjunction etc.

Ultimately, what we deem necessary is what is logically necessary and therefore what follows logically from your own assumptions. Assumptions may include beliefs about the contingent world as well as mathematical and linguistic conventions.

EDIT

2 + 2 = 4 is only true if we assume the usual meaning of '2', '=' and '4'. The idea that 2 + 2 = 4 is necessarily true results from confusing the statement "2 + 2 = 4", which is true given the usual assumptions, with the fact that a set of four elements can be partitioned into two subsets of two elements, which is always the case as far as we know. However, a fact is a fact, not a statement, and so it is neither true nor false, and so it is not necessarily true either. You could call that a category error. The statement "a set of four elements can be partitioned into two subsets of two elements" is true but only under the usual linguistic assumptions, and so not necessarily true, *in itself* as it were.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136975/discussion-on-answer-by-speakpigeon-necessarily-false-propositions).